# Exit graph window using matplotlib.pyplot in terminal?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, plot, terminal

I wrote a command-line program in `Python` using `matplotlib.pyplot` and `argparse`.  I input the data and get the scatterplot i'm looking for and then a window pops up with my graph.  This is cool but how can I exit that window from the terminal ?

I ended up adding an argparse argument `--exit` that does `sys.exit()` but it's not working...when I do `ctrl+Z` it stops my script but the graph window stays open.

**How can I exit this matplotlib.pyplot graph window from the terminal?**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import argparse, sys


def main():
    #(i). Add arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)

    parser.add_argument('--exit', action = 'store_true', help = 'Exit graph')

    options = parser.parse_args()

    x_coordinates = [1,2,3,4,5]
    y_coordinates = [3,3,3,3,3]
    size_map = [20,20,20,20,20]

    plt.scatter(x_coordinates,y_coordinates, s = size_map)
    plt.show()

    if options.exit:
        sys.exit()

#Initiate
if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: Why not show a demonstrative code? [ask]

Comment: I didn't think the code was necessary.  It's a standard scatterplot but i'll add it in.